# Increasing screen resolution of linux terminal using GRUB2

Tags: linux, display, terminal, resolution, grub2

I need to change the screen size of Linux terminal, particularly  increase the resolution and thus increase the space for output.

Target environment:

V.Platform      : Oracle VirtualBox 6.1
Guest OS        : OpenSuse Leap 15.2
Used booloader  : Grub2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solution allowed to perform the primary task, and to solve the issue with error message reported by the guest OS:
"**drm:vmw_host_log [vmwgfx]] ERROR Failed to send host log message**".
Also, mentioned here: "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500178/issue-while-booting-kubuntu-on-virtualbox-drm-vmw-host-log-vmwgfx-error-failed"

Here is the solution:

**1. Stage #1** - retrieve the available video modes using the Grub2 terminal

```
# On system loading press 'c' on to enter to the Grub2 terminal;
#
# Configure output - optional (not mandatory) step;
set pager=1
#
# list supported video modes - also vbeinfo command can be used here;
videoinfo
#
# note down the target resolution - in my case, it was 1152x864x32;
#
# reboot the system
reboot
```

**2. Stage #2** - OS terminal - configuring Grub2

```
# load OS and login using your user account;
#
# start edit Grub2 config file using Vi or your preferred text editor;
vi /etc/default/grub
#
# add or edit the next entries to the config file:
#   GRUB_GFXMODE=1152x864x32
#   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
#   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
# ATTENTION: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameter can already contain some other parameters, just append your parameter to the existing list of parameters using the space char as a separator;
# save the file and exit from the text editor - in Vi ":wq";
#
# rebuild the actual configuration of the Grub2 bootloader
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
#
# Reboot the system
shutdown -r now
#
# Enjoy!
```

**3. Materials**

- Increasing the screen resolution of linux console with GRUB in
  VirtualBox – Ronald Toussaint
  (http://www.ronaldtoussaint.nl/2018/01/24/increasing-the-screen-resolution-of-linux-console-with-grub-in-virtualbox/)
- The Boot Loader GRUB 2 | Reference | openSUSE Leap 15.2
  (https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book-opensuse-reference/cha-grub2.html)
- Setting the resolution or character size for boot and text consoles
  on SLE 12 and newer | Support | SUSE
  (https://www.suse.com/de-de/support/kb/doc/?id=000018747)